# Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform

Tags: java, windows, dll, java-native-interface

I am trying to use [SVMLight](http://svmlight.joachims.org/) from Java, using the [JNI wrapper on this page](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/~mtb/):

```
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("lib/JNI_SVM-light-6.01/lib/svmlight");
  }
```

I get the following error:

> ... lib\JNI_SVM-light-6.01\lib\svmlight.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll
>   on a AMD 64-bit platform

Can I solve this by recompiling the .dll for 64 bit? **How would I go about doing this?** Is there some other workaround I can use? SVMLight makes the C source code available.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Yes, you'll have to recompile the DLL for 64-bit.  Your only other option is to switch to a 32-bit JVM, or otherwise get some 32-bit process to load the DLL on your behalf and communicate with that process somehow.

Comment: How can I switch to a 32 bit JVM? Is that an argument I can pass, or do I need to download and configure something new?

Comment: Download and install a 32-bit jvm.

Comment: @Rosarch: Yup, a 64-bit machine can run 32-bit executables.  That will be the easiest way to get a 32-bit DLL to work.

Comment: "Yes, you'll have to recompile the DLL for 64-bit." How?

Comment: @JohnPerry you need to be the author of the DLL or have access to the DLL's codebase. Usually, you will use either CMake or Visual Studio to compile into a dynamically linked library.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with a Java application using tibco dll originally intended to run on Win XP. To get it to work on Windows 7, I made the application point to 32-bit JRE. Waiting to see if there is another solution.

Comment: Hi can you elaborate on how you got your app to point to 32-bit JRE? Is that something you did in your IDE or programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer to first question: yes.

Longer answer: maybe; it depends on whether the build process for SVMLight behaves itself on 64-bit windows.

Final note: that call to System.loadLibrary is silly. Either call System.load with a full pathname or let it search java.library.path.

Comment: I asked multiple questions. Which are you answering "yes" to? ha.

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue in win64bit and JVM 64bit

Was solved by uploading dll to system32

Comment: that's not possible, the location of the file doesn't change anything

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you are setting PATH to **Program Files (x86)** not **Program Files**. That solved my problem.

Comment: Maybe you mea to "use a jvm that is found under Program Files (x86), to ensure it's a 32 bit version" ??

Answer (score 1):

Got this from - http://blog.cedarsoft.com/2010/11/setting-java-library-path-programmatically/

If set the java.library.path, need to have the following lines in order to work.

```
Field fieldSysPath;
fieldSysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField( "sys_paths" );
fieldSysPath.setAccessible( true );
fieldSysPath.set( null, null );
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to

Project properties >> Run >> VM options

and put this address:

```
-Djava.library.path="C:\opencv\build\java\x64"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just go to install download [jdk_x86](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
 and it install in Program Files (x86) and set the jre path in your project. Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem when run red5(tomcat) on Windows x64 that previous worked under Windows x32, got next error:

```
 INFO pool-15-thread-1 com.home.launcher.CommandLauncher - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\....\lib\Data Samolet.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
INFO pool-15-thread-1 com.home.launcher.CommandLauncher - at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
```

Problem solved when I installed Java x32 version and set next

"Environment variables"

*"User variables for Home"*

JAVA_HOME =>  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk.1.6.0_45

*"System variables"*

Path[at the beginning] => C:\Program Files\Java\jdk.1.6.0_45;..

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue related to this and was reading

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\opencv\build\java\x86\opencv_java2413.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform "
```

and it took me an entire night to figure out.

I solved my problem by copying the dll in `C:\opencv\build\java\x64` to my system32 folder. I hope this will be of help to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer for those who compile from the command line/Command Prompt. It doesn't require changing your `Path` environment variable; it simply lets you use the 32-bit `JVM` for the program with the 32-bit `DLL`.

For the compilation, it shouldn't matter which `javac` gets used - 32-bit or 64-bit.

```
>javac MyProgramWith32BitNativeLib.java
```

For the actual execution of the program, it *is* important to specify the path to the 32-bit version of `java.exe`

I'll post a code example for `Windows`, since that seems to be the OS used by the OP.

**Windows**

Most likely, the code will be something like:

```
>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre#.#.#_###\bin\java.exe" MyProgramWith32BitNativeLib
```

The difference will be in the numbers after `jre`. To find which numbers you should use, enter:

```
>dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\"
```

On my machine, the process is as follows

```
C:\Users\me\MyProject>dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java"
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 0000-9999

 Directory of C:\Program Files (x86)\Java

11/03/2016  09:07 PM    <DIR>          .
11/03/2016  09:07 PM    <DIR>          ..
11/03/2016  09:07 PM    <DIR>          jre1.8.0_111
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  107,641,901,056 bytes free

C:\Users\me\MyProject>
```

So I know that my numbers are `1.8.0_111`, and my command is

```
C:\Users\me\MyProject>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin\java.exe" MyProgramWith32BitNativeLib
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about you should just change .dll from x64 to x86, in the native library.

for example:-
you might have selected this (C:\opencv\build\java\x64).

instead you select this for native library(C:\opencv\build\java\x86).

Answer (score 0):

My windows laptop has both the clients 32 & 64 bit I started facing all of sudden then I reordered the path variable like below

Before:

```
C:\app\oracle64\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin;
C:\app\oracle32\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin;
```

After:

```
C:\app\oracle32\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin;
C:\app\oracle64\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin;
```

started working... Hope this helps everyone.

Answer (score 0):

For your Native library location, use X64 over X86. At least this fixed problem I had.

Answer (score 0):

no build for Win64 necessary.

Download 64x version on https://tomcat.apache.org/download-native.cgi

from one of the mirrors i.e.

https://mirror.checkdomain.de/apache/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/native/1.2.28/binaries/tomcat-native-1.2.28-openssl-1.1.1k-win32-bin.zip

from zip use:

> bin\x64\tcnative-1.dll