# is there a way of running the leibict java sample on a windows7 64bit platform?

Tags: java, netbeans-7, ussd

I get this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   C:\Users\Tjava Guru\Documents\NetBeansProjects\USSDTest\ussdjni.dll:
>   Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)   at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1939)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1864)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1854)  at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)  at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)    at
>   com.leibict.ussd.USSD.(USSD.java:49)  at
>   ussdtest.Main.main(Main.java:31) Java Result: 1

Comment: Yes, but you'll  need to use a 32bit JVM. Also: please check that your question is properly formatted next time. And having a question in the body is a big plus as well.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, i hv both the 32bit and 64bit JDK installed and i still get the same error

Comment: That's because you're *executing* your code with the 64bit JVM, you probably need to specify the 32bit one explicitly, when you launch the application.

Comment: wow!! thanx a lot bru...i managed to run it, i changed the platform nd it worked :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113080/cant-load-ia-32-bit-dll-on-a-amd-64-bit-platform)