# Error when running a 32 bit .dll on a 64 bit JVM Inteliij

Tags: intellij-idea, jvm

I am getting the below error when I try to execute the below line of code in my project. I added a 64 bit JDK to my project properties . I am using Intellij as my IDE

System.loadibrary(smsjavaagentapi)

Fatal Error: Exception from System.loadibrary(smsjavaagentapi) java.lang.unsatisfiedLinkError smsjavaagentapi.dll: Can't load IA 32 bit .dll on an AMD 64-bit platform

I think the problem is that I am using a 64 bit JVM and I am trying to run a 32 bit .dll. I don't have an option to install 32 bit JDK on my machine and add it to my project properties nor I can port the .dll to 64 bit . Is there a work around for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113080/cant-load-ia-32-bit-dll-on-a-amd-64-bit-platform)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limitation at the OS level which prevents a 32-bit shared library being loaded by a 64 bit process, so your options are

- modify the OS to allow this (not easy)
- migrate the DLL to 64-bit by recompiling it.
- install a 32-bit JVM (easier)
- download a 32-bit JVM and unpack it without install it. (doesn't require any special permission)

You might find you can get a version of IntelliJ which ships with a 32-bit JVM, or install another program which installs a 32-bit JVM and use just the JVM.