# Cannot load JDBC driver class 'oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver' despite adding JAR file

Tags: java, oracle, datasource, ojdbc, myeclipse

I'm trying to run a java web application on myEclipse by deploying it on Tomcat v7.0. I'm trying to connect it to my Oracle database 19c. I've added the ojdbc jar file in the classpath like shown  [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpAjW.png).
Yet I'm still getting the error.

And the root cause of the error is shown to be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3JGX.png)

Below is my context.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
<WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
<Resource name="jdbc/secure_mail" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl"
    username="c##scott" password="mathsformula" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10"
    maxWait="-1" />
</Context>
```

And this is my datasource definition:

```
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        try {
            InitialContext initContext = new InitialContext();

            Context env = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");

            ds = (DataSource) env.lookup("jdbc/secure_mail");

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            throw new ServletException();
        }
    }
```

Any idea what could be causing this? Am I adding the wrong JAR file, or is it because I'm using Tomcat v7.0? Thanks.

Edit:

I'm also getting this error message displayed at the beginning of the console whenever I run the web application:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\kuman\Downloads\apache-tomcat-7.0.109-src\apache-tomcat-7.0.109-src\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\bin\tcnative-1.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2452)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2508)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2704)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2669)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:807)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1907)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.<init>(Library.java:42)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Library.initialize(Library.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init(AprLifecycleListener.java:180)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.isAprAvailable(AprLifecycleListener.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.setProtocol(Connector.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.<init>(Connector.java:69)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ConnectorCreateRule.begin(ConnectorCreateRule.java:62)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1276)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:518)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:183)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1386)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2725)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:541)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:888)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1224)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:665)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Jun 19, 2021 12:12:40 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
```

Comment: What you have done is added the JAR to the >build< classpath.  It is not needed there. What you actually need to do is to add it to the >runtime< classpath.

Comment: One way is given in the answer below.  It might also be possible to put the JAR into your webapp's WAR file ... in the standard place.

Comment: There is no webapp folder, and I'm not finding any WAR file anywhere.

Comment: see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113080/cant-load-ia-32-bit-dll-on-a-amd-64-bit-platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the jar in the CATALINA_HOME/lib directory, i.e. the lib folder of you tomcat installation dir.