# I get this "UnsatisfiedLinkError " while trying to use the jpcap Java library

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, dll, jar, jpcap

Using: windows 10, VScode, intel cpu.
I'm getting this error after importing the jar files into my project and running an example code from Github.

[image: error message stack trace]

```java
import net.sourceforge.jpcap.capture.*;
import net.sourceforge.jpcap.net.*;


/**
 * jpcap Tutorial - Example 5
 *
 * @author Jonas Lehmann and Patrick Charles
 * @version $Revision: 1.2 $
 * @lastModifiedBy $Author: pcharles $
 * @lastModifiedAt $Date: 2001/07/02 16:44:21 $
 *
 * Run example and then initiate a ping on the network.
 * The example will produce output only if ICMP (ping)
 * packets are captured.
 */
public class App 
{
  private static final int INFINITE = -1;
  private static final int PACKET_COUNT = INFINITE; 

  // BPF filter for only capturing ICMP packets
  private static final String FILTER = "proto ICMP";

  private PacketCapture m_pcap;
  private String m_device;
  
  public App() throws Exception {
    // Step 1:  Instantiate Capturing Engine
    m_pcap = new PacketCapture();

    // Step 2:  Check for devices 
    m_device = m_pcap.findDevice();

    // Step 3:  Open Device for Capturing (requires root)
    m_pcap.open(m_device, true);

    // Step 4:  Add a BPF Filter (see tcpdump documentation)
    m_pcap.setFilter(FILTER, true);

    // Step 5:  Register a Listener for jpcap Packets
    m_pcap.addPacketListener(new PacketHandler());

    // Step 6:  Capture Data (max. PACKET_COUNT packets)
    m_pcap.capture(PACKET_COUNT);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        App example = new App();
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }
}


class PacketHandler implements PacketListener 
{
  private static int m_counter = 0;
  private static int m_icmpCounter = 0;

  public void packetArrived(Packet packet) {
    m_counter++;

    if(packet instanceof ICMPPacket)
      m_icmpCounter++;
    else
      System.err.println("Packet slipped thru filter: " + 
                         packet.getClass().getName());

    System.out.println("Total Packets: " + m_counter + 
                       "   ICMP Packets: " + m_icmpCounter);
  }
}
```

I've been trying to import and use this library for two days with C++ and java, any help would be welcome

I imported the dll file from lib to my JDK directory and imported the jars into the Referenced libraries in VScode, and Yeah I have npcap installed on my PC.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113080/cant-load-ia-32-bit-dll-on-a-amd-64-bit-platform)

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the x64 dll and now I have another error `PacketCapture: loading native library jpcap.. ok
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'java.lang.String net.sourceforge.jpcap.capture.PacketCapture.findDevice()'`

Answer (score 0):

Is the `jpcap.dll` file on the Java library path?

Add the `jpcap` path to ***path*** in the system environment variable.

Comment: which path exactly to the `jpcap.jar` or `jpcap.dll` ?

Comment: The jar is a Java reference and should be placed under the project reference, and the dll is placed on the path variable.